# How get predictions from a specific PyTorch model

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I would like to obtain the prediction values from this PyTorch model (https://github.com/allegro/allRank) but when I run:

```
 model(val_dl)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: LTRModel.forward() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'mask' and 'indices'
```

Now, mask and indices are used inside of the fit function (inside of train_utils.py) and I assume these must be the weights.

Is it maybe possible to obtain these from the model object after training is finished? Or would it make more sense to get the predictions inside of the fit function after it has finished fitting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give inputs to the model in prediction time as you give inputs in training. From the [github code](https://github.com/allegro/allRank/blob/master/allrank/models/model.py), the forward method is defined as

```
    def forward(self, x, mask, indices):
        """
        Forward pass through the whole LTRModel.
        :param x: input of shape [batch_size, slate_length, input_dim]
        :param mask: padding mask of shape [batch_size, slate_length]
        :param indices: original item ranks used in positional encoding, shape [batch_size, slate_length]
        :return: model output of shape [batch_size, slate_length, output_dim]
        """
        ...
```

So, for prediction, you should create the attention mask and indices as it is done for the training. These two are not weights but tensors created from the 'y' tensors as in [inference code](https://github.com/allegro/allRank/blob/master/allrank/inference/inference_utils.py):

```
    with torch.no_grad():
        for xb, yb, _ in dataloader:
            X = xb.type(torch.float32).to(device=device)
            y_true = yb.to(device=device)

            input_indices = torch.ones_like(y_true).type(torch.long)
            mask = (y_true == losses.PADDED_Y_VALUE)
            scores = model.score(X, mask, input_indices)
        ...
```

where "model.score" is a very similar method to forward method.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. A few questions: Where would you run this? Inside of main or inside of train_utils inside of the fit function? Also, why did you add model.score? And then, where would I get the predictions? After scores? y_pred = model.forward(X, mask, input_indices)?

Comment: Where you run the code is more of a design choice in my opinion. I did not add model.score, I just copied the code from the github. When you check model.forward and model.score, these two methods are written very similarly, so model.forward should also work.

Comment: The reason I ask about where to run the code is because some of the objects or variables that are referenced inside the code you copied only exist inside of the tain_utils.py or fit function, and are not returned to the result object that calls them in main.py.

Comment: But it is still not quite clear to me how this would work. Would you be able to specify how exactly you would run this (either in main.py or train_utils.py)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easer to pass the mask and indices back to the main script that calls the fit function and then run model(X_Test, mask, input_indices) there? It is not clear to me how to do that either though, since mask and input indices are only defined within certain functions.

Comment: Since the _LTRModel_ contains a [`transformer.encoder`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerEncoder.html)  which the inputs are given firstly into this part in forward pass, you need the _mask_ and _input_indices_ created.  I would make the dataloader's output in each batch as **x, y, indices** and create the mask where they are used. as it is on [train_utils.py](https://github.com/allegro/allRank/blob/master/allrank/training/train_utils.py). Check the definitions of _fit_ and _loss_batch_ methods. PS main.py also uses a similar type of dataloader as I described.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. I will try this. I'll post my results here in a bit, might be helpful to others as well. Thank you for you help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the predictions by running this in main:

slates_X, slates_y = __rank_slates(val_dl, model)

But the output shape is not clear to me. The number of rows in slates_y is corresponds with the number of qids in my dataset. But I would imagine it should match the number of rows instead, since I want the predicted rank of each row.